# LUKS: Determine which keyslots match which pass phrase

Tags: luks

I have a LUKS encrypted disk. It has 3 keyslots, and I know the pass phases for two of them.

How do I determine which keyslots I know the pass phrases for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way would be to use `--debug` when unlocking the device, it prints which keyslot it tries to use, so with two passphrases you need just two runs of `luksOpen` to see which keyslot which passphrase "belongs" to.

Example where I provided password for third keyslot:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sde a --debug
...
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
...
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 1.
...
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 2.
...
Key slot 2 unlocked.
```

If you want to check from a script, you can use `--key-slot <num>` with `luksOpen` and cycle for every keyslot for every passphrase you know, unlocking wrong keyslot with a wrong passphrase will simply fail (you can also use this together with `--test-passphrase` to just check whether the passphrase is correct or not without actually unlocking the device). This will also help if you have two keyslots with the same passphrase, the `--debug` example above won't tell you that.

So something similar to this should do the trick:

```
for i in {0..2}; do
   for pass in "a" "b" "c"; do
      echo $pass | cryptsetup open /dev/sde a -q --test-passphrase --key-slot $i >/dev/null 2>&1
      ret=$?
      [ $ret -eq 0 ] && echo "$pass is passphrase for keyslot $i" && break
      done
done
```

```
a is passphrase for keyslot 0
b is passphrase for keyslot 1
c is passphrase for keyslot 2
```